# Missing right parenthesis in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, syntax-error, parentheses

I have query like this:

```
select a.NPP, a.NAMA, a.JOB, a.STATUS, a.last_updated, 
a.UNIT_BESARAN, a.PERIODE, a.GOAL_ID,a.USER_APPROVED, 
a.DATE_APPROVED, a.USER_SUBMITTED, a.DATE_SUBMITTED 
from (select a.NPP, a.NAMA, b.job, b.status, to_char(b.last_updated, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') AS last_updated, 
b.periode , b.goal_id, b.USER_APPROVED, b.DATE_APPROVED, b.USER_SUBMITTED, b.DATE_SUBMITTED, 
case when b.UNIT_BESARAN is null then a.UNIT_BESARAN else b.UNIT_BESARAN end UNIT_BESARAN 
from OL_PEGAWAI_DAILY a left join PFM_GOAL_HEADER b on a.PERSON_ID=b.PERSON_ID and b.last_status=1 and 
b.periode = '2015' and b.status is null order by b.STATUS asc) a where UNIT_BESARAN like 'DIVISI SOLUSI % KEAMANAN TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI' 
and a.status is null and npp not in (

--here subquery
select f.NPP from (select f.NPP, g.status, g.goal_id, 
case when g.UNIT_BESARAN is null then f.UNIT_BESARAN else g.UNIT_BESARAN end UNIT_BESARAN 
from OL_PEGAWAI_DAILY f left join PFM_GOAL_HEADER g on f.PERSON_ID=g.PERSON_ID and g.last_status=1  and 
g.periode = '2015' and g.status='2' and g.job is not null and g.last_updated is not null order by g.STATUS asc) f 
where UNIT_BESARAN like 'DIVISI SOLUSI %' and f.status is not null order by goal_id asc

) order by goal_id asc
```

In the subquery, when I try to run it, I don't get any errors. When I try to run the all queries i get an error like this:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not allow the usage of the `order by` clause in a subquery used with the `in` operator (presumably because it's just pointless - the `in` operator does not care about order). Unfortunately, using it produces an ORA-00907 instead of some straight-forward error that actually explains what you did wrong.

To make a long story short - remove the `order by goal_id asc` from the query used in the `in` operator and you should be fine.